# See if a date is in same or previous calendar week

Tags: excel, date, calendar, excel-formula

I answered a question about testing to see if a date was in the same, previous, or even earlier week compared to a reference date.

In this case the question was about testing to see if the earlier date was less than 5, less than 10 or 10 or more working days before the reference date, and referred to a previous question about testing to see if the earlier date was less than 7, less than 14, or 14 or more days before the reference date.

I wanted to try and answer the related question of whether a given date is in the same 'calendar week' (Sunday to Saturday), or in the previous 'calendar week', or in an earlier calendar week.

My first thought was to use the WEEKNUM function, so if the reference date is TODAY(), this would be

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-WEEKNUM(A2)>1,"Old",IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-WEEKNUM(A2)>0,"Last week","This week"))
```

However this doesn't work across year boundaries because WEEKNUM starts at 1 for each new year.

In a normal year, WEEKNUM runs from 1 to 53 (because there are just over 52 weeks in the year).  So it would appear that the above formula could be adapted to work across year boundaries simply by adding the YEAR(A2) * 52 (or possibly 53) to the WEEKNUM.

However consider a leap year which starts on a Saturday and finishes on a Sunday. In this case WEEKNUM runs from 1 to 54.

The last such leap year was 2000 and the next one is 2028.

I'm not clear if it will work in every case.

The reference date is 10th January 2001.

[image]

I will try and post an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario, `WEEKDAY` is your friend, and it will also allow you to define the start day of your week.

using the formula part `(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),11)` and `A2-WEEKDAY(A2,11)`, we can test if the values are equal (=Current Week), or older:

```
=IF((TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),11))=(A2-WEEKDAY(A2,11)),"This Week",IF((TODAY()-WEEKDAY(today(),11)-7)=(A2-WEEKDAY(A2,11)),"Last Week","Old"))
```

You can also modify the comparison to give the appropriate number of weeks, instead of running against the IF nesting limit:

```
=((TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),11))-(A2-WEEKDAY(A2,11)))/7 & " Week(s) old"
```

the *magic number* to change for the beginning of the week is the `11` in the Weekday function - change to any number from 11 to 17 to start your day of the week wherever you need it to

Answer (score 0):

Have accepted SeanC's answer as a good one and nice that it can be extended to the more general question of how many calendar weeks between two dates.

I was going to go back to first principles and suggest the following (for a week starting at Sunday)

```
=IF(INT((TODAY()-1)/7)-INT((A2-1)/7)>1,"Old",IF(INT((TODAY()-1)/7)-INT((A2-1)/7)>0,"Last week","This week"))
```

or this for a week starting at Monday

```
=IF(INT((TODAY()-2)/7)-INT((A2-2)/7)>1,"Old",IF(INT((TODAY()-2)/7)-INT((A2-2)/7)>0,"Last week","This week"))
```

It works because dates start from Sunday, 1st January 1900 which is represented as the number 1.

But the other answer is more readable - the WEEKDAY function is doing the arithmetic for you.